# How to display scrollbar in nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I Dear.
I have use Nestedscrollview to wrap many group of button and recyclerview. but the problem I got is can't display scrollbar on the right.

does nestedscrollview have property for display scrollbar.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
.....
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
```

Comment: use   `android:scrollbars="vertical"` attribute

Comment: @sohanshetty It this very help full thanks.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687679/how-to-show-the-scrollbar-in-a-nestedscrollview